# Troubling removing string in Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am having trouble understanding what to do next. The following code removes all the duplicate numbers but I also need to remove the strings without converting them to numbers. I'm not sure how to proceed...

```
var arr = [ 10, 44, 55 ,66 , 77 , 55 , 44 , 3 , 3 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 54 , "henry", "33", "£", "66"]
var max = {};
function biggerThanMax(arr){
    return arr.filter(function(item,index){
        return arr.indexOf(item) >= index;
    });
};
biggerThanMax(arr)
```

Comment: Your array is missing the closing `]`

Comment: ... and your function is missing a `{`

Comment: What should the output be? It's still a little bit vague what you want to achieve. By "remove the strings", do you mean remove all strings, or just the ones that are duplicates of an already existing number?

Comment: Should `"33"` be removed?

Answer (score 1):

use `typeof x` to check the type of variable x

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

```js
var arr = [
  10, 44, 55, 66, 77, 55, 44,
  3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 54,
  "henry", "33", "£", "66"
]
var max = {};

function biggerThanMax(arr) {
  return arr.filter(function(item, index) {
    return typeof item == 'number' && arr.indexOf(item) >= index;
  });
};
console.log(biggerThanMax(arr))
```

---

You also have a couple of typos (which are likely a typo in your example)

- Unclosed array
- Missing biggerThanMax opening bracket.